# Disable 'hide toolbar' in Finder

Tags: finder, dmg

Is it possible to permanently overwrite the 'Hide Toolbar' and 'Hide Sidebar' setting in the Finder, particularly in DMG images with downloaded Applications, so that the toolbar and sidebar are *always visible*?

That way it would be possible to drop applications directly into the Applications folder.

Comment: That's one reason I keep Applications on the right side of my dock.

Comment: Sure, same thing here.

Comment: I do not believe there is a way to override custom window settings on DMGs.